# What is the best way to maintain control box?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I am using c#.net here.

The `combobox1` contains a number from 1 to unlimited, say n, if the `combobox1.text == 1`, then `textbox1` and `textbox2` appears, `combobx1.text == 2` then `textbox1` to `textbox4` appears, `combobox1.text==n` then `textbox1` to `textbox2*n` appears.

How do I set the `textbox` objects to be added dynamically? the item in my combobox1 is limited to 8,that means I have only 16 textboxes.What if i want the textboxes is unlimited to the number of n.
for example in console.

```
console.read("Input n : ");
int n = convert.toint16(console.readline());//100
double[] x = new double[n];
double[] y= new double[y];
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
x[i]=convert.todouble(console.readline());
y[i]=convert.todouble(console.readline());
}
```

something like that,but in windows form.
I am learning to make regression interpolation program, so I need the x and y. That's why if `combobox1.text==1` then 2 textboxes should be visible

Thank you

Comment: You can assign a value to the tag of the controls you want to show and find those controls when combo changes.

Comment: **real** code here may suggest shortcuts.

Comment: Create a few List<Control>. One for all and one for each value and loop over the totalList checking each for being contained in s current valueList!

Comment: You need to use `Events`, have a look at the following pages and have a go:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx        
http://www.dotnetperls.com/form

Comment: Please don't reask the same quesiton in a different format:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201760/how-to-maintain-textbox-and-labelcontrols

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

```
var choice = int.Parse(comboBox1.Text);

// show 2 textboxes per value, so 10 should be max for 20textboxes
if (!Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Contains(choice))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("only 1 to 10 is allowed : " + comboBox1.Text);

var textBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10, textBox11, textBox12, textBox13, textBox14, textBox15, textBox16, textBox17, textBox18, textBox19, textBox20 };
for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
    textBoxes[i].Visible = i < choice * 2;
```

Comment: wow.thankyou!It works,but the throw exception is error,so I commanded out that if.the rest is good.thankyou!

Comment: actually you should keep it, but add a `!` before `Enumerable`.

Comment: I am sorry,what is the usage of that throw exception?I changed the range to 2,8,then I added "10" to the column,then my program showed error.the exception didnt work.

Comment: Nvm, you can remove it, there is no possibility of running into an `IndexOutOfrangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

My take would look like this:

- Give each participating control a `Tag` that contains all allowed values " 1 3 4 5 " etc. Note the spaces!
- Set the visibility of each like this: `yourControl.Visible = yourControl.Tag.ToString.Contains(value.ToString(" #0 "));`

One block all in all and one `Tag` to maintain per control.

Note that each `Tag` can contain multiple values and each value can be part of multiple `Tags`!

For more complex maninpulation including changing requirements dynamically you could still create `List<Control>` and loop over them..

Note that while your question implies some sort of rising relation between the values chosen and the textboxes I do not make use of it as it is a accidental and volatile one. Instead I separate concerns and store the visibilty groups in the Tags of each Control. This is visible, easy to maintain and still very fast to check.

To avoid the block you can still add all participating controls into a `List<Control>` and loop over it:

```
List<Control> allBoxes = null ; 

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  allBoxes = new List<Control>() { textBox1, textBox2, label1..};
  foreach (Control ctl in allBoxes) ctl.Tag = "";  // initialize..

  textBox1.Tag =  " 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 "
  textBox2.Tag =  " 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 "
  textBox3.Tag =  " 5 6 8 9 10 "

  textBoxXYZ.Tag =  " 1  3 7 5 10 "
```

}

```
void SetVisibility(int value)
{
     foreach (Control ctl in allBoxes) 
       ctl.Visible = ctl.Tag.ToString().Contains(value.ToString(" #0 "));
}
```

Comment: well,I am still new to this control thing,since I just learned OOP and windows form.so all the textboxes are stored in a list of Control?

Comment: Not in my answer. You could if you need to get more control, but for the original question you don't need to do that. Also: If adding them to a List<Control> or a List<TextBox> you would just store references for easy access in a loop; similar to an aray but nicer to work with. The Controls woud still sit on the Form. Let's assume you at some point want to clear all TextBoxes. Then having all in a`List<TextBox> allBoxes` makes this easy: `foreach (TextBox tb in allBoxes) tb.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to limit the number of text boxes that can be added, you should handle the selected index changed event of the combo box by actually creating new text boxes dynamically as you need them, setting their position (left and top), and adding them to the form's controls property. You would also handle removing text boxes by actually removing them from the form and disposing of them, rather than making them invisible.

You're also going to want to put them in a panel with a vertical scroll bar instead of plopping them on the form so you don't run out of space.

You can use arrays or instances of the List class to keep track of your text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an enum like this

```
public enum  StyleVisibleOfControls{Style1,Style2,Style3}
```

And use like this

```
public StyleVisibleOfControls Style
{ 
    set{
        // you can use switch too
        if ( value ==StyleVisibleOfControls.Style1 )
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (value ==StyleVisibleOfControls.Style2){
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do this in your extended combobox too

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "2"){
   Style  = StyleVisibleOfControls.Style1;
}
else if (comboBox1.Text == "3"){
    Style  = StyleVisibleOfControls.Style2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign a value to the tag of the controls you want to be shown (assign 1 to those controls that should be shown when combo is 1, etc) and in your combobox_selectedIndexChange:

```
var val = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

var cs = Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(c => c.Tag != null && int.Parse(c.Tag.ToString()) <= val).Select(c => { c.Visible = true; return c; }).ToList();
```

Comment: @TaW Why not? Am I missing something?

Comment: Per OP the Tags would need to contain multiple values. Doable, see my answer.. –

Comment: @TaW Why does the tag need multiple values? combo value "2" shows textbox2, 3, 4. Combo value "3" shows textbox2, 3, 4, 5, 6. So if you use tag "1" for textbox2, 3, 4 and tag "2" for textbox5 and 6 then selecting value "1" from the combo will show textbox2, 3, 4. Selecting "2" from the combo will show textbox1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: You assume that there is a mathematical relation ('<=') between value and visibility. This make for a inflexible and obscure code. So it will probably work as long as he sticks to that rising relation. A totally weird and unnecessary dependency. What if requirements change and he need to exclude textbox3 form value 2? Not my downvote, but well earned imo..

Answer (score -1):

You could also group the controls inside of containers and initialize the containers visibility to false:

```
panel1.Visible = false;
panel2.Visible = false;
panel3.Visible = false;
```

Then you could do this:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "2")
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "3")
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }

        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "4")
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel3.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

This is similar to what you you already have but you could group several controls inside of containers and show them all at once.

Comment: Not really flexible, imo as each control can only be part of one group.